# Inconsistent d3-legend positioning when using an external font

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I'm using [d3-legend](https://d3-legend.susielu.com/) to create a legend for a D3 map. The map makes use of an externally loaded font, with the entire map being removed and redrawn when a dropdown menu is used.

d3-legend allows the spacing between legend items to be controlled by using `.shapePadding` but this doesn't seem to be being honoured consistently in my case - the spacing changes after the map is redrawn. See the screenshots below.

[image: screenshots of the issue]

NB: I'm finding that the issue is occurring inconsistently here - if I make a minimal tweak to the code the issue seems to go away. The issue occurs consistently when I run the same code locally.

```js
function drawMap1() {

  // Set the size and margins of the svg
  var margin = {
      top: 60,
      right: 10,
      bottom: 40,
      left: 10
    },
    width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 780 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  d3.selectAll("#map1 > *").remove();

  // Create the svg element
  var svg = d3
    .select("#map1")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  // Set the colour scale
  var quantize = d3.scaleQuantize(); // domain and range are set as part of loading dataset

  quantize
    .domain([0.6, 1])
    .range(d3.quantize(d3.interpolate("rgb(230,0,126)", "rgb(45,170,225)"), 4));

  // Add a legend
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "legendQuant")

  var legend = d3.legendColor()
    .shapeWidth(30)
    .orient("vertical")
    .shapePadding(2)
    .scale(quantize)
    .labelFormat(d3.format(".0%"));

  svg.select(".legendQuant")
    .call(legend);
}

function updateMap1DateSelector(value) {
  drawMap1()
}

drawMap1()
```

```css
.d3-map svg {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="data:,">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css' type='text/css' media='screen,projection' />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700&amp;lang=en" />
</head>

<body>
  <select id="date-selector-map1" class="dropdown-selector" onchange="updateMap1DateSelector(value)" style="float: right;">
    <option value='20201015'>15 October 2020</option>
    <option selected value='20201105'>5 November 2020</option>
  </select>
  <div id="map1" class="d3-map"></div>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-legend/2.25.6/d3-legend.min.js'></script>
  <script src='legend.js'></script>
</body>
```

I can hard-code the position of the legend items using code such as this:

```
d3.select(".legendCells")
    .selectAll(".cell")
    .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
        return "translate(" + 0 + "," + i*19.5 + ")"
    });
```

But it would be good to understand what's actually causing the issue - I think it's to do with the use of an external font, as removing the relevant line of CSS gets rid of the issue. And it'd be good to know what a less hacky solution is.

Comment: Could you add side by side images of the weird and normal behaviours so we can identify them as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, every time the shapes are drawn, the following code is executed:

```js
const cellSize = textSize.map((d, i) =>
  Math.max(d.height, shapeSize[i].height)
)
```

Here, `textSize` is a bounding box of the text nodes and `shapeSize` a bounding box of the rectangles, or swatches. The first time, when the font hasn't loaded yet, the `textSize.height` is 16 pixels, later it is 23.

If you know this might happen, you could [delay the JavaScript until the fonts have loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27080155/5015356).

If the legend is drawn against a single-coloured background, you could also increase the rectangle size to 23px and add a thick stroke that matches the background colour:

```js
function drawMap1() {

  // Set the size and margins of the svg
  var margin = {
      top: 60,
      right: 10,
      bottom: 40,
      left: 10
    },
    width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 780 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  d3.selectAll("#map1 > *").remove();

  // Create the svg element
  var svg = d3
    .select("#map1")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  // Set the colour scale
  var quantize = d3.scaleQuantize(); // domain and range are set as part of loading dataset

  quantize
    .domain([0.6, 1])
    .range(d3.quantize(d3.interpolate("rgb(230,0,126)", "rgb(45,170,225)"), 4));

  // Add a legend
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "legendQuant")

  var legend = d3.legendColor()
    .shapeWidth(30)
    .shapeHeight(23)
    .orient("vertical")
    .shapePadding(2)
    .scale(quantize)
    .labelFormat(d3.format(".0%"));

  svg.select(".legendQuant")
    .call(legend);
}

function updateMap1DateSelector(value) {
  drawMap1()
}

drawMap1()
```

```css
.d3-map svg {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

.swatch {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="data:,">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css' type='text/css' media='screen,projection' />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700&amp;lang=en" />
</head>

<body>
  <select id="date-selector-map1" class="dropdown-selector" onchange="updateMap1DateSelector(value)" style="float: right;">
    <option value='20201015'>15 October 2020</option>
    <option selected value='20201105'>5 November 2020</option>
  </select>
  <div id="map1" class="d3-map"></div>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-legend/2.25.6/d3-legend.js'></script>
  <script src='legend.js'></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Fixed using WebFontLoader, as the linked answer suggests. Thanks @Ruben.